# Can I record in stereo using Scarlett 2i2 and Audition?

Tags: recording, stereo, audio-interfaces, production, mono

I have purchased a Scarlett 2i2 Audio Interface and will be purchasing an Audio Technica AT2035.

1. Am I able to record in stereo using the Scarlett 2i2 from my standard output jack on my Mac, or would I have to purchase a splitter and then have two different inputs setup on the Scarlett?

Say for instance I want to pull audio from online by just recording what I hear instead of figuring out a way to save the audio into a different format. When I try it now I have an AUX cable from my headphone jack on the MAC into an 1/8 adapter plugged into the 2i2. But it is only recording mono and I am unable to convert it to stereo in Audition.

2. Would I be better off at just getting some type of mixer?

Comment: The Scarlett 2i2 inputs are mono instrument/line inputs, so you would need a splitter. I'm not sure about Macs but in Windows, the system(output) audio can be recorded in any DAW if you have the right drivers, maybe its the same for Mac.

Comment: Are you going to record a voiceover too?

Comment: Yeah, I am mostly looking to import the audio into Audition and then record a voice on a separate track.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to record what you hear in mac you can use Soundflower instead of doing it using your audio interface. here are some tutorial for that:

[from softonic](http://features.en.softonic.com/how-to-record-internal-sound-on-a-mac)

[from instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-record-audio-from-your-computer-using-Quick/?ALLSTEPS)

if you need to record a voice over for that I should say you can't do it realtime in this way as you need to change your input from your audio interface to Soundflower. but using a sequencer like Audacity, Logic pro, etc. you can record your voice over it in a new track.